# How to delete object in firebase without knowing full url in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code to add new object in firebase.

```
private void addProductVariant(String pid, String vid, String mrp, String sellPrice) {
    final String uid = getUid();
    String key = databaseReference.child("shops-product-list").child(uid).push().getKey();

    ShopProductVariant shopProductVariant = new ShopProductVariant(pid, vid, mrp, sellPrice);
    Map<String, Object> shopProductVariantValues = shopProductVariant.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/shops-product-list/" + uid + "/"+ key, shopProductVariantValues);

    databaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

This works fine.

Now i want to delete the same object. i don't know the location (full url). This is code i have written so far.

```
private void deleteProductVariant(String pid, String vid, String mrp, String sp){

    final String uid = getUid();
    ShopProductVariant shopProductVariant = new ShopProductVariant(pid, vid, mrp, sp);

    //databaseReference.child("shops-product-list").child(uid).child("product-list").setValue(shopProductVariant);

    //mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(name);
}
```

How to get key value and delete data object on that location?

Comment: If you don't know the `key` of the item to delete, how will you identify which of the child items to delete? Or do you want to delete all child items with the same `pid`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, i want to delete only single item with same pid and vid  pass as function args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only a single item matching the conditions, I'd recommend keeping the key of that item somewhere. Looking up the same item is both more expensive than needed and likely to become a problem at some point.

But within your current requirements, this should work:

```
private void deleteProductVariant(String pid, String vid, String mrp, String sp){

  final String uid = getUid();

  DatabaseReference listRef = databaseReference.child("shops-product-list").child(uid).child("product-list");

  listRef. addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot variantSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        ShopProductVariant variant = variantSnapshot.getValue(ShopProductVariant.class);
        if (variant.pid == pid && variant.vid == void) {
          variantSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      throw databaseError.toException();
    }
  })
}
```

You'll note that this code loads the entire product list for a user to find the item to delete. The reason for this is that you need to check against two values (`pid` and `vid`), while Firebase queries can only check against a single condition. If this is a performance problem, you can consider adding a helper property that combines the two values (see [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)).

Since you say the combination of `pid` and `vid` is unique for your app, you might even consider using those as the key of your products instead of using a push ID:

```
String key = pid + "_" + vid;
```

Deleting then becomes as simple as:

```
private void deleteProductVariant(String pid, String vid, String mrp, String sp){
  final String uid = getUid();

  DatabaseReference listRef = databaseReference.child("shops-product-list").child(uid).child("product-list");

  DatabaseReference itemRef = listRef.child(pid + "_" + vid);

  itemRef.removeValue();
}
```